# post request with link_to in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, post, post-parameter

How do I make a remote POST request with custom parameters with a link_to helper in rails 3?

I tried something like this:

```
link_to 'Submit', model_path, :query => "value", :remote => true, :method => :post
```

The POST works and the control comes to the action in the controller, but I don't get the POST parameters in params or anywhere else.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I got it. I need to pass parameters to the model_path function itself like,

```
 model_path(:query => "value")
```

Didn't realize it was a function all along. Paradigm change...

Comment: Typically however, you'll name the parameter as: model_name[parameter_name]. e.g. <%= link_to job_search.query, job_searches_path("job_search[query]" => "#{job_search.query}"), :method => :post %>

Answer (score 1):

You need made 2 things

1. Call the `csrf_meta_tag` helper in your head of HTML
2. Add the rails.js for your javascript library. Prototype or jQuery.